# When is that not dependent

Tags: american-english, british-english, relative-clauses

Dependent clauses include clauses that may begin with **that**, who, whom, whose, which, where, when, and why. (Judy Hopkins -- Sentence Variety)

That can begin a complete sentence though correct? It's different to the other words listed.

*That she was told about the wedding made no difference.*

Comment: The others can start sentences, just not (usually) *declarative* sentences.

Answer (score 2):

> That's right.

As in the above, *that* can certainly begin a complete sentence.

In your example, *(That the wedding ...), that* begins a complete sentence *and* a dependent clause. *That she was told about the wedding* is a clause and not a "complete sentence" (in most  likely contexts). It's a *that clause."* That clauses can function as objects or subjects in sentences.

No, it's not different from the other words given in the sense that all of them can be used in the same way:

*Who comes to the wedding is not important.*